# Rails: Calculating the sum of several results based on different field types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My users have_many Investments (model) associated to them. What I need to do is calculate the **sum of all their :contributions** (a column on the Investments model) on a monthly basis (I'll get to that below).

In my **controller**, I have:

```
   #get Investment types that are Roth IRAs, Traditional IRAs, etc.
    @getira = Investment.where(user_id: current_user, investmenttype: ["Roth IRA","Traditional IRA","Other"])
```

Typically I would just add .sum(:contributions) onto that query. However, not all contributions are created equal.

Investments also have a :contributionfrequency field, which is a string where users select "Monthly", "Quarterly", or "Annually"

So I have added this below in that same **controller**:

```
   investment = @getira.find(params[:contributionfrequency])

    # evaluate IRA contribution frequency
    if investment.contributionfrequency == "Quarterly"
      @contribution_quarterly = (investment.contribution.to_i * 4) / 12
    elsif investment.contributionfrequency == "Monthly"
      @contribution_monthly = investment.contribution.to_i
    elsif investment.contributionfrequency == "Annually"          
      @contribution_annually = investment.contribution.to_i * 12
    end
```

When I do this, I get this error:

**Couldn't find Investment without an ID**

I'm not sure if making the correct query, or if I'm not passing in the right fields here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be receiving error `Couldn't find Investment without an ID` on the following line

```
 investment = @getira.find(params[:contributionfrequency])
```

This simply means that `params[:contributionfrequency]` is `nil` i.e., you have not passed the key `:contributionfrequency` in `params`.

As per the chat session with OP, `params[:contributionfrequency]` was removed and a direct query was used:

```
@contribution_quarterly = Investment.where(user_id: current_user, investmenttype: ["Roth IRA","Traditional IRA","Other"], contributionfrequency: ["Quarterly"]).sum(:contribution) 
@contribution_monthly = Investment.where(user_id: current_user, investmenttype: ["Roth IRA","Traditional IRA","Other"], contributionfrequency: ["Monthly"]).sum(:contribution) 
@contribution_annually = Investment.where(user_id: current_user, investmenttype: ["Roth IRA","Traditional IRA","Other"], contributionfrequency: ["Annually"]).sum(:contribution)
```

Comment: how do I pass the key :contributionfrequency in params?